# How to use Python Web Scraping to download CSV file then convert it to Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I'd like my script to do the following:

1) Access this [website](http://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html):  
2) Import a CSV file titled "Sales Data with Leading Indicator" 
3) Convert it to pandas Dataframe for data analysis.

Currently, the code I have is this:

```
response = request.urlopen("http://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html") 
csv = response.read()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pandas.read_csv()` method accepts a URL to a csv file as its buffer, so

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('http://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/datasets/BJsales.csv')
```

Should basically work. See further info [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) .

Comment: Thank you very much. I have 2 additional questions. How did you know to take out .html extension and add dataset title and csv? Secondly, why doesn't the method work for the "Guerry" dataset or even 'forbes"?

Comment: The website you linked to in your question is not a csv file, it's just contains links to csv files. You mentioned you wanted the "Sales Data with Leading Indicator" file so I just used its URL, nothing fancy.